# How to automatically create a new file based on an existing file within Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

It's the first time I used Google Cloud, so I might ask the question in the wrong place.
 
Information provider upload a new file to Google Cloud Storage every day. 
The file contains the information of all my clients/departments.

I have to sort through information and create a new file/s containing the relevant information for each department in my company .so that everyone gets the relevant information to them (security).

I can't figure out what are the steps I need to follow, to complete the task.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a process that **starts automatically** and subsequently generates a new file once you upload something to Google Cloud Storage.

The easiest way to handle this is using [Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification). You can set up **Object Change Notifications** per bucket and this will send a POST request to an URL that you can define.

You can then easily set up a server (or run it on [app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart)) that will execute an action based on the POST request that it receives.

There is an even simpler option (although still in *alpha*) named [cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). **Cloud functions** is a serverless service that provides event based microservices (e.g. 'do this' if a new file is uploaded on GCS). This means you only have to write the code that defines what needs to happen if a new file is uploaded and then Cloud Functions will take care of executing the code when you upload a file to GCS. See this [tutorial on using cloud functions with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage).